# SQL results to string with wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose you have a table like this:

```
ID     FNAME      LNAME
1      Bob        Smith
2      Sally      Jones
```

A simple SELECT * FROM [Table] will return all rows. But what if you wanted to build a single string out of the results, and the column names are unknown? In other words, this will not work:

```
SELECT ID + ',' + FNAME + ',' + LNAME FROM [Table]
```

because you don't know the column names. Additionally, COALESCE won't work because it doesn't accept wildcards. Ideally you want to execute something like this:

```
SELECT dbo.FunctionThatSplitsResultsToString(*) FROM [Table]
```

and have it return

```
1,Bob,Smith
2,Sally,Jones
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Essentially, you want to export a CSV file from your table. Are you restricted to SQL or can you use any other tools (e.g. Java programs)?

Comment: Why are the columns unknown? If you're looking to export your data to CSV then SQL Management Studio has a Data Export option.

Comment: What are you planning to do with your result set?

Comment: Lukas Elder - yes, restricted to doing it in T-SQL only.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but `SELECT * FROM table FOR XML AUTO` might be close to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a corrected version of the answer @Igor gave. In addition to concatenating comma characters between the values, it converts NULL values to an empty string (because concatenating a string to NULL results in a NULL value).

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)='SELECT '
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(max) = 'Table_Name' -- <-- Set the target table name here

SELECT @sql=@sql+N'ISNULL(CAST(' + name +' as NVARCHAR(max)), '''')+'',''+'
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID(@TableName)

SELECT @sql=SUBSTRING(@sql,1,LEN(@sql)-5)+N' FROM ' + @TableName
--SELECT @sql -- uncomment to see the query string

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

As the first Igor noted, the solution is dynamic SQL.  You need to construct the underlying SQL statement correctly.

The following code casts all columns to varchar() and then concatenates them together.  The final form of the SQL removes the last "+" sign and adds the from statement:

```
declare @sql varchar(max);

select @sql = (select 'cast('+coalesce(column_name, '') + ' as varchar(255)) +'
               from information_schema.columns
               where table_name = <whatever>
               for xml path ('')
              );

select @sql = left(@sql, len(@sql - 2)) + ' from t';

exec(@sql);
```

I admit to being US-centric and rarely using internationalization.  The whole thing also works with nvarchars().

Comment: Can you explain tihs a little? :)

Comment: I thought I did.  This creates dynamic sql that concatenates the columns together.  It does this using the XML method of string concatenation.  Print out @sql to see what the results are.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

GO
DECLARE @ColumnsList VARCHAR(MAX), @SelectStatement VARCHAR(MAX),@TargetTable VARCHAR(250) ,@FINALSQL  NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TARGETTABLE ='TempData'

SELECT @ColumnsList =  COALESCE( @ColumnsList+' + '','' +' ,'')   + 'Cast('+ A.COLUMN_NAME + ' AS Varchar(250))'
FROM (select Column_Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME= @TARGETTABLE) A
SELECT @FinalSql = 'Select ' +@ColumnsList + ' FROM ' + @TARGETTABLE

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @FINALSQL
GO